# how do you store a value when a condition happens in pinescript ? ONLY ONCE

Tags: python, pine-script

lets say i want the price when 2 EMAs crosses and use that price to create another variable as an stoploss but in realtime the price always changes in realtime candle so my stoploss and takeprofit  always changes.
i understand i have to use `varip` but i dont know how to use it with `valuewhen`

please help me correct my code. thank you :)

```
varip float Current_Close = na

/////
Long_Cond = crossover(ema1 , ema2)

////
Current_Close := valuewhen(Long_Cond , close , 0)

///
Stop_loss = Current_Close * 0.995

// "Risk Ratio 1/1"

takeprofit__long := Current_Close * (1 + (1 * ((Current_Close - Stop_loss) / Current_Close)))
```

i don't know how to use `varip` in this code with `valuewhen` .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

captureValueOnce(cond, float value)=>
    var float store = na
    if cond and na(store)
        store := value
    store

Long_Cond = ta.crossover(ta.ema(close, 50) , ta.ema(close, 200))
plot( captureValueOnce(Long_Cond, bar_index) )
```